# How to implement Key Value Coding Validation

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-bindings, key-value-coding

I have an ArrayController bound to a master/detail UI which is working just great. I'm now trying to implement validation at the model level.

[Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/Validation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002173-CJBDBHCB) indicate the follow should work to validate individual properties:

```
-(BOOL)validateName:(id *)ioValue error:(NSError * __autoreleasing *)outError
```

So if I have a model property of "ProjectName", the following should automatically fire:

```
-(BOOL)validateProjectName:(id *)ioValue error:(NSError * __autoreleasing *)outError
```

But unfortunately, it just doesn't happen :(

However, interestingly, if I use the "catch all" method as below, it DOES work:

```
-(BOOL)validateValue:(inout __autoreleasing id *)ioValue forKey:(NSString *)inKey error:(out NSError *__autoreleasing *)outError  {
```

Within the method I can code to determine which property is being validated of course, but I can't figure out why it completely ignores the accessor method?

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: Please include the declaration of your property.

Comment: `@property (strong) NSString *projectName;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The validation method does not automatically fire - from your linked documentation:

> In general, key-value coding does not perform validation automatically—it is your application’s responsibility to invoke the validation methods.

And also:

> You can call validation methods directly, or by invoking validateValue:forKey:error: and specifying the key. The default implementation of validateValue:forKey:error: searches the class of the receiver for a validation method whose name matches the pattern validate:error:. If such a method is found, it is invoked and the result is returned. If no such method is found, validateValue:forKey:error: returns YES, validating the value.

Which explains your second situation.

Comment: OK, well, the issue has magically resolved itself and I have no idea why or how... I had restarted Xcode, though I find it hard to be believe that would be the cause.